# java.util.regex.Matcher confused group

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I'm having trouble getting the right group of a regex match. My code boils down to following:

```
Pattern fileNamePattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+_\\w+_\\w+_(\\w+)_(\\d*_\\d*)\\.xml");
Matcher fileNameMatcher = fileNamePattern.matcher("test_test_test_test_20110101_0000.xml");

System.out.println(fileNameMatcher.groupCount());

if (fileNameMatcher.matches()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < fileNameMatcher.groupCount(); ++i) {
        System.out.println(fileNameMatcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

I expect the output to be:

```
2
test
20110101_0000
```

However its:

```
2
test_test_test_test_20110101_0000.xml
test
```

Does anyone have an explanation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Group(0) is the whole match, and group(1), group(2), ... are the sub-groups matched by the regular expression.
Why do you expect "test" to be contained in your groups? You didn't define a group to match test (your regex contains only the group \d*_\d*).

Comment: Thank you very much! Was not aware of that default behavior.

Comment: And yes I missed a pair of parenthesis in my code, just edited it for correctness.

Answer (score 2):

Group 0 is the whole match. Real groups start with 1, i.e. you need this:

```
System.out.println(fileNameMatcher.group(i + 1));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Was not aware of that default behavior.

Answer (score 2):

- `group(0)` should be the entire match ("test_test_test_test_20110101_0000.xml");
- `group(1)` should be the sole capture group in your regex ("20110101_0000").

This is what I am getting. I am puzzled as to why you'd be getting a different value for `group(1)`.

Comment: Thanks I got it now :)
Sorry for the confusion I forgot some parenthesis in my code, see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

actually your for loop should INCLUDE groupCount() using "<**=**" :

```
for (int i = 0; i <= fileNameMatcher.groupCount(); ++i) {
    System.out.println(fileNameMatcher.group(i));
}
```

thus your output then will be:

```
2
test_test_test_test_20110101_0000.xml
test
20110101_0000
```

the groupCount() will not count group 0 matching the whole string.

first group will be "test" as matched by (\w+) and

second group will be "20110101_0000" as matched by (\d*_\d*)