# Why do I find only one group in java regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I'm writing a very simple sample code about regular expression but failed to work with `group`.

The regular expression is: `rowspan=([\\d]+)`

The input string is: `<td rowspan=66>x.x.x</td>`

I'm testing it on online regex engine and obvious the group `66` can be captured, see snapshot below:

[image]

Based on the javadoc,

> Group zero denotes the entire pattern, so the expression m.group(0) is
>   equivalent to m.group().

So I think there should be two groups and group 0 should be `rowspan=66`, the group 1 should be `66`. However, all I can get from below code is the former.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        String input = "<td rowspan=66>x.x.x</td> ";
        String regex = "rowspan=([\\d]+)";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        if(matcher.find()){
            for(int i = 0; i < matcher.groupCount(); i++){
                System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The output is:

```
rowspan=66
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I don't think this is an exact duplicate of the mentioned question. This patter _does_ seem to contain groups.

Comment: [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#groupCount--): "Returns the number of capturing groups in this matcher's pattern.

Group zero denotes the entire pattern by convention. **It is not included in this count**. "

Comment: and is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/12989917/85421 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/5716703/85421 , ... (stopped searching since someone thinks this is not duplicae)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
for(int i = 0; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
}
```

`matcher.groupCount()` is `1`, so if you use `<` you will iterate only on index `0`.

Comment: Hmmm, it helps. The groupCount here really confuses. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with your code has to do with understanding what the `Matcher#groupCount` method does.  From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#groupCount()):

> Returns the number of capturing groups in this matcher's pattern. 
>    Group zero denotes the entire pattern by convention. It is not included in this count.

In other words, your `for` loop would only iterate once, assuming you have a single capture group.  But you were printing the first group, which is the entire pattern:

```
for (int i=0; i < matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
}
```

Instead, just iterate while you have a match, and then access the groups you need.  I don't see much of a problem with hard coding the capture groups, because if a match occurred, then by definition the capture groups inside that match should be present as well.

```
String input = "<td rowspan=66>x.x.x</td> ";
String regex = "rowspan=(\\d+)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

### Demo

Note: Your pattern also looks a bit strange.  If you want to match a digit via `\\d`, then you don't also have to put that into a character class.  Hence I used the pattern `rowspan=(\\d+)` in my code.

Answer (score 1):

I've always been a fan of named groups for regular expressions and Java supports this via the special group construct `(?<name>)`. This makes retrieving the correct group easier and you won't mess things up if you later add another group earlier in the expression. It halso has the side-effect that it removes any confusion regarding `matcher.groupCount()`.

Change your regular expression to `rowspan=(?<rowspan>[\\d]+)`

And your code to:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        String input = "<td rowspan=66>x.x.x</td> ";
        String regex = "rowspan=(?<rowspan>[\\d]+)";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        if(matcher.find()){
            System.out.println("Entire match: " + matcher.group());
            System.out.println("Row span: " + matcher.group("rowspan"));
        }
    }

}
```

And you'll get:

```
Entire match: rowspan=66
Row span: 66
```

Comment: great solution/suggestion!